# Display search results Multisite WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress Multisite and want to display search results from blog category from all the child sites on home site.

Here is the search.php file code. I can switch the blog to display the results but want to merge all the search from child sites.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Search Results pages
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage xsite
 * @since xsite 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div class="SearchBlue">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12"><h1>Search Results</h1></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">

                <?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; query_posts("s=$s&paged=$paged&cat=2"); ?>
                <?php $searchString = get_search_query(); ?>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchInputStatic" placeholder="<?= $searchString ?>">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                <a id="searchSubmitStatic" class="btn btn-primary" title="search" href="#">Go</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <?php
                global $wp_query;
                if ($wp_query->found_posts > 0) {
                    ?>
                    <p class="resultsCount"><?= $wp_query->found_posts ?> results found.</p>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <p class="resultsCount">Sorry, no results were found. Please try again.</p>
                <?php } ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- container -->
</div><!-- SearchBlue -->
<div class="clearfix"></div>

    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; query_posts("s=$s&paged=$paged&cat=2"); ?>
    <div class="container" id="searchResultsContent">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <?php $searchString = get_search_query(); ?>

                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php
                        get_template_part('content', get_post_format());
                    ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
        </div><!-- row -->
    </div><!-- container -->
<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```